# Continue the iteration when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX

Tags: oracle

I have a procedure `procedure1` given as follows,

Values of table TESTTABLE123 are ,

[image]

```
create or replace procedure procedure1 as 
CURSOR TESTTABLE124_CUR IS SELECT *  FROM TESTTABLE123 ;
begin

     FOR i IN TESTTABLE124_CUR LOOP 
       BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TESTTABLE124 (select * from TESTTABLE123);

       EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('duplicate value');
      CONTINUE;
      END ;
      END LOOP;
      commit;
end procedure1;
```

While executing this procedure I am getting the error,
`An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.`

1. But why even the first row is not inserted in to the second table.
2. My requirement is if an error occurs it should continue the iteration and to insert the upcoming rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to insert **all rows** in each iteration. In your case you want to insert **one** row only inside the loop (row-by-row processing), so that if it fails only one row fails and the next one can be inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 AS
   CURSOR TESTTABLE124_CUR IS
      SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE123;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN TESTTABLE124_CUR LOOP
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO TESTTABLE124 VALUES (i.col1, i.col2...i.coln);      
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('duplicate value');         
      END;
   END LOOP;
   -- COMMIT; don't commit inside procedures
END procedure1;
```

Alternatively, you could only insert the rows that won't raise the exception (that would be more efficient):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TESTTABLE124
      (SELECT * 
         FROM TESTTABLE123 t_old
        WHERE t_old.pk NOT IN (SELECT t_new.pk FROM TESTTABLE124 t_new));
   -- COMMIT; don't commit inside procedures
END procedure1;
```

Replace `pk` with the appropriate unique column names.

Comment: In the first part I need to write `i.col1, i.col2...i.col100` if I have 100 columns?

Comment: Yes, in general you'll have to write all column names in static SQL. However in your case you could use a rowtype, see [Oracle: Insert rowtype data into another table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867022/119634).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert it as an `RECORD` itself.. using the `RECORD`(*Implicit* creation for the SELECT/CURSOR) in the `FOR LOOP` variable!

```
create or replace procedure procedure1 as 
CURSOR TESTTABLE124_CUR IS SELECT *  FROM TESTTABLE123 ;
begin

     FOR REC IN TESTTABLE124_CUR LOOP 
       BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TESTTABLE124 
            VALUES REC ;
        --- Just Specify the name.. But the column order should be same
       EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('duplicate value');
            CONTINUE;
        END ;
      END LOOP;
      commit;
end procedure1;
```

Comment: Yes.. You can just replace `CONTINUE` with `NULL;` too.. Just _suppressing_ the exception

Answer (score 0):

A hint can be used instead of exception handling:

```
INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(TESTTABLE124 , TESTTABLE124_PK) */
INTO TESTTABLE124 ...
```