# Error Testing PL/SQL Insert Stored Proc

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to Oracle and stored procedures. I'm having some issues getting a simple stored proc I wrote to run using SQL Developer.

Here is my stored proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_user_create(
  user_row IN t_user%ROWTYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T_USER (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL)
  VALUES(user_row.FIRST_NAME, user_row.LAST_NAME, user_row.EMAIL);
  COMMIT;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;

END sp_user_create;
```

When I try to run it with SQL Developer I get the following screen.

[image]

It complains the line USER_ROW PL/SQL RECORD is not valid but SQL Developer generated this?

[image]

UPDATE:

I got it working by using the following code to test.

```
DECLARE
  USER_ROW t_user%rowtype;
BEGIN
  --USER_ROW := ('BOB','MALAKI','sithlord@google.com');
  USER_ROW.FIRST_NAME := 'BOB';
  USER_ROW.LAST_NAME := 'MALAKI';
  USER_ROW.EMAIL := 'MALIKI@power.com';

  SP_USER_CREATE(
    USER_ROW => USER_ROW
  );
--rollback; 
END;
```

The question remains though can the USER_ROW be defined in a single line instead of setting each column individually? That can be tedious when there are lots of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"PL/SQL record" is just a placeholder for actual data type, not the data type itself, as sql developer has no reliable way to determine it using data dictionary. Replace it with "t_user%rowtype", which is a type of user_row parameter.

Comment: I got it working per your suggestion. Thanks much! Quick question though, is there a way to declare a row in a single line instead of setting each column value individually like USER_ROW.FIRST_NAME = 'SOMETHING'?

Comment: no, there's no way to do this with pl/sql records. you can do it with object types though - they have a constructor syntax, but on the other hand they are schema objects and can't be declared as table%rowtype. you have to choose what you need more here.

Answer (score 1):

I have an addition to the accepted answer.
It is possible to set USER_ROW by using select:

```
select 'BOB' as FIRST_NAME, 'MALAKI' as LAST_NAME, 'MALIKI@power.com' as EMAIL 
into USER_ROW from dual;
```

You can also select values into USER_ROW from another table.

P.S.:
Also, instead of the lines:

```
INSERT INTO T_USER (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL)
VALUES(user_row.FIRST_NAME, user_row.LAST_NAME, user_row.EMAIL);
```

in your stored procedure, you can write:

```
INSERT INTO T_USER VALUES user_row;
```

Some additional information you can see:
[Oracle: Insert rowtype data into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866915/oracle-insert-rowtype-data-into-another-table)