# Can I use INSERT ALL with multiple recordtype variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

Given a PL/SQL block where I have access to 2 recordtype variables, I want to insert these 2 records into the same table in a single statement, but my attempts to use `INSERT ALL` have failed thus far. Is it possible to use `INSERT ALL` with record variables at all?

Here is some code that works, using dedicated inserts:

```
DECLARE
    mProperty1 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    mProperty2 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
    INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES mProperty1;
    INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES mProperty2;
    ...
END;
```

If I try to convert the statement to a `INSERT ALL` though, it fails with an error message:

```
DECLARE
    mProperty1 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    mProperty2 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    ...
BEGIN
    ...
    INSERT ALL
          INTO MyTable VALUES mProperty1
          INTO MyTable VALUES mProperty2
          SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
    ...
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 14, column 60:
>   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>   ORA-06550: line 13, column 60:
>   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>   ORA-06550: line 13, column 60:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   ORA-06550: line 12, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way to make this statement work?

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866915/oracle-insert-rowtype-data-into-another-table

Comment: @KedarLimaye I'm not entirely sure how that thread helps in this case. It doesn't appear to be using `INSERT ALL` and is dealing with cursors, which is not what I'm working with here.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using insert all?

Comment: @KedarLimaye In this particular case, I just wanted to make my script as short and performant as possible so I went straight for it assuming the API would be orthogonal with the normal `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using different methods but succeeded with the only following:

**Method 1:**

Using particular record names from `%ROWTYPE` field

```
DECLARE
    mProperty1 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    mProperty2 MyTable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    mProperty1.COL1 := 1;
    mProperty2.COL1 := 2;
    INSERT ALL 
    INTO  MyTable VALUES (mProperty1.col1)
    INTO  MyTable VALUES (mProperty2.col1)
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
END;
/
-- may be bad choice but you can use like this
```

**Method 2:**

If you are concerned about performance then you can also use this method:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE mProperty_TYPE IS TABLE OF MyTable%ROWTYPE;
    mProperty mProperty_TYPE;
BEGIN
    mProperty := mProperty_TYPE();
    mProperty.EXTEND(2);
    mProperty(1).COL1 := 3;
    mProperty(2).COL1 := 4;
    FORALL I IN 1..mProperty.COUNT 
    INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES mProperty(I);
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=962296d594e677bcc6856a6b5b8fabeb)